# Android Compose Hilt navigation graph scoped dependencies

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

How can i scope dependencies to google navitaion graph lifecycle ? I didn't see any component in documentation to meet my requirements

Maybe there is some kind of trick to achieve what i want with presented components?